# Google anayltics.txt on a lightsail wordpress instance

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, amazon-lightsail

We are unable to sign in to account into our Google Analytics account and have found the following docs which tells us to create an "analytics.txt" at the root of our domain so Google can verify ownership

https://support.google.com/analytics/troubleshooter/7264014?hl=en#ts=7271146

Our website is hosted by an AWS Lightsail Wordpress instance. How can we add the "analytics.txt" to the root of our domain so it is accessible via ourwebsite.com/analytics.txt?

Answer (score 0):

For the Bitnami WordPress solution, the root path is set to /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs.